# Show Progress Bar for task of one Process in another Process

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, .net-3.5, progress-bar

I have a system with the following components:

Process A - A console app that acts as a service - Services clients through WCF

Process B - A console app that acts as a service - Services clients through WCF

Process C - A small WInForm app that acts as a service - Services clients through WCF

Though we can start each of the above processes individually by double clicking but we decided to have another Process "Service Manager" that hides the individual UI's and starts all the processes above and shows a kind of consolidated UI. The communication between the Service Manager Process and the different processes is right now done through TCP but we can move that to WCF anytime we wish.
Before anybody asks, so TCP was initially used for "Mono" but that is not on the cards right now.

Now when Process A is started from the ServiceManager, lets say Process A is performing a time consuming task, since it does not have its own UI, so Service Manager needs to show a progress bar for the Process A task.

In Process A i have every information to show a deterministic progress bar, but how do i send that data over to the Service Manager. Like "Step 1 of 1000" etc.

Is there a recommended "Design Pattern" or any ideas that i can start with.
Every process started from the Service Manager needs to use the same code for sending any progress task data over to the Service Manager(basically implement some interface). Every Process has its own progress bar on the Service Manager UI.

.Net 3.5

used
Language C#

Thanks

Comment: `NamedPipes` is an option, here is a sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Interprocess-Communication-858cc9c7 . Your Service Manager would act as PipeServer and your A, B, C processes would act as PipeClients.

Comment: Do you mean that you know the progress of each on the client side already and you just need to pass that info over to a different thread? Or are you saying that you know the progress on the server side and need to somehow kick that back to the client for processing?

Comment: Yes, the progress details are known in each client. Need to pass the info on to a different process(not thread). So looking for some design where each client uses the same interface/design to pass the data on to the Service Manager. The service manager also would incorporate something that it can differentiate between the processes from which it receives the message so as to update the correct progress bar. Also the client processes can run independently as well, so they should work even if the Service Manager has not started them in which case each process is responsible for its own GUI.